# Check Box binding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 checkboxes. Lets call them `cb1`,`cb2` and `cb3`. The `cb3` should be checkëd when `cb1` and `cb2` are checked. How do I Implement this in WPF.? I am new to WPF.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Providing code examples helps us help you.

Comment: Show how you handle (use) `IsChecked` values now. It's very easy to solve with MVVM in ViewModel.

Comment: Are you using a viewmodel?

Comment: Are you using MVVM or Code Behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a ViewModel, just add a new computed property to that.

A simple view model would look like:

```
public class MyVieWModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _cb1Checked;
    private bool _cb2Checked;

    public bool CB1Checked
    {
        get { return _cb1Checked; }
        set
        {
            _cb1Checked = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CB1Checked"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CB3Checked"));
        }
    }

    public bool CB2Checked
    {
        get { return _cb2Checked; }
        set
        {
            _cb2Checked = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CB2Checked"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CB3Checked"));
        }
    }

    public bool CB3Checked
    {
        get { return _cb1Checked && _cb2Checked; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

After setting `CB1Checked` or `CB2Checked`, you need to raise the event that `CB3Checked` has also changed.

Your XAML would look something like (and this is from memory...):

```
<CheckBox IsChecked={Binding CB1Checked}" />
<CheckBox IsChecked={Binding CB2Checked}" />
<CheckBox IsChecked={Binding CB3Checked, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

As @wkl points out in the comments, the third checkbox should be a one-way binding since the value can't be set.

Some MVVM frameworks might make this a little easier for you, I've not used any to be able to recommend though.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you have to use a OneWay-Binding for cb3 as you bind to a readonly property. And you may want to disable cb3 to keep the user from manually changing it and thus breaking consistency.

Comment: @wkl excellent point, I'll try to edit that in later when I've got the tools to hand

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this for a single checkbox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cb3" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=cb2}" />
```

**I assume the other checkbox is called** `cb2`.

For multiple checkboxes I recommend a `Binding` in you `DataContext`.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=CB_1_Checked}" Content="CheckBox 1" />

public bool CB_1_Checked 
{
   get { return _cb_1_checked; }
   set
   {
       _cb_1_checked = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();

       //Notify that CB_3_Checked may have changed:
       OnPropertyChanged("CB_3_Checked");
   }
}
```

Do this for CB1 and CB2.

Add this for CB3

```
//Will return 'true' when both are checked (but lacks OnPropertyChanged !)
public bool CB_3_Checked => (CB_1_Checked && CB_2_Checked);
```

Or with a little more options:

```
private bool _cb_3_checked;

public bool CB_3_Checked 
{
   get 
   {        
       if(CB_1_Checked && CB_2_Checked)
       {             
          _cb_3_checked = true; 
       }
       return _cb_3_checked;          
   }
   set
   {           
       _cb_3_checked = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Read more about [Bindings here.](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/)